# Windows 10 PC creating Hotspot?

Tags: windows-10, hotspot

There's this wifi network which doesn't appear on my Laptop but on all other devices. It is named "DIRECT-ZK*pcnamehere*msKX"

But when i turn on the hotstop, this is disappears and the actual hotspot appears.

What exatcly is causing this and should I be worried? (The network is password protected)